# SaveFileDialog Error

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to make a simple Windows Form Application that saves a text file. I'm having trouble with the following program, it gives me:

> Empty path is not a legal

```
namespace Filing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SaveFileDialog file = new SaveFileDialog();

            file.Filter = "Text (*.txt) | Word File *.doc";
            file.Title = "Save a file";
            File.WriteAllText(file.FileName, richTextBox1.Text);

            file.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void button_exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause you didn't "show" the [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) yet, so the fileName is empty.

Try moving the showDialog upward:

```
private void button_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SaveFileDialog file = new SaveFileDialog();

        file.Filter = "Text (*.txt) | Word File *.doc";
        file.Title = "Save a file";
        //Ask the user to select the file path and file name, don't forget to handle cancel button!
        if(file.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
              File.WriteAllText(file.FileName, richTextBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the writing statement as the following.

```
if(file.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
     File.WriteAllText(file.FileName, richTextBox1.Text);
```